# Get value from selected checkboxes (Checkbox array)

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, checkbox

I have a array of checkboxes, 33 in total.
Because the checkboxes are all over the page, it needs to be in an array (right?).

The code-behind looks like this:

```
CheckBox[] variableName = new CheckBox[33];

        variableName[0] = idCheckBox1;
        variableName[1] = idCheckBox1;
        variableName[2] = idCheckBox1;
        variableName[3] = idCheckBox1;
```

and so on...

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="idCheckBox1" runat="server" Value="1" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="idCheckBox2" runat="server" Value="2" />
...
```

The checkboxes are totally optional.
Now how do i get the value of the checked boxes only in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does **NOT** need to be an array.
This is how you get all the **CHECKED** checkboxes in your form from the CodeBehind:

```
var names = formCollection.AllKeys.Where(c => 
                    c.StartsWith("idCheckBox") && 
                    formCollection.GetValue(c) != null &&
                    formCollection.GetValue(c).AttemptedValue == "1");
```

Comment: Also, maybe you could benefit from the CheckBoxList Class:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx

Comment: Where did you get 'formCollection' from? If i use my form1, there is no AllKeys.

Comment: Alright, in my case 'form1' then... But when i use it like this:
var names = form1.AllKeys.Where(c =>
                    c.StartsWith("idCheckBox") &&
                    form1.GetValue(c) != null &&
                    form1.GetValue(c).AttemptedValue == "1");

the AllKey isn't recognized. I'm using System.Collections...

Comment: The Linq namespace was already imported :)
Well, when i use 'Request.Form.AllKeys', AllKeys is recognized. Strange... (sorry, not a big c# expert ;)